# Problem running hokuyo_node

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Everyone!

I've installed the hokuyo_node package and just started the hokuyo tutorials (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode).

However, when i type this command:

$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node

The terminal displays the following message:

[ WARN] [1350269609.097397459]: The use_rep_117 parameter has not been set or is set to false.  Please see: http://ros.org/wiki/rep_117/migration
[ERROR] [1350269615.350188127]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
timeout reached (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadline) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting

I tried to search information about this error, but haven't found anything so far.
Do you have any clue about what is wrong?

I am beginner at using ROS, so please try to explain with details, if it's possible...
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45850/problem-running-hokuyo_node/) by [throliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3385/throliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [throliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/3385/throliveira/) on 2012-10-15**:
Hey guys!

I'm actually using a Serial-USB converter cable.
When i connect Hokuyo through the cable, is not shown at the default ACM* driver, but at USB0.
I tried to configure the permissions for USB0, using sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0.
My sensor is URG-04lx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

maybe you have more than one device connected to your computer that uses ACM driver. If so run:

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node _port:=/dev/ttyACMx
```

Edit:

By default, hokuyo_node assumes that you have connected with USB, which uses ACM. As tfoote wrote in the comment:

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

should do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-11-24**:
With your edit use /dev/ttyUSB0 instead of ACM0

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-09-08**:
hi guys i try to use hokuyo laser but when i write "rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node" this error occurd" [rospack] Error: stack/package hokuyo_node not found" what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it seems like you are facing communication problems. Does

```
  ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
```

show the correct permissions for the device? You need to have read and write permissions. Is the laser connected properly? Maybe try a different USB cable or something. Which laser are you using? I don't know if Hokuyo maybe has different communication protocols for different lasers.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1